# Jetpack sharing buttons placement css

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I guess that Jetpack places their sharing icons at the end of posts by default. How can I place them on top of post under H1 post title? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS property that changes a div's or HTML tag's position. Therefore custom CSS is not applicable to your situation. What you can try is search for "social icons" etc. in page builder of Jetpack to change its position. 
https://jetpack.com/support/extra-sidebar-widgets/social-icons-widget/

Answer (score 0):

I found this information here, but I do not have LIKE buttons, only sharing on my posts.
Url is //jetpack.com/support/sharing
Then below there a topic named:
**How can I move where the sharing icons are displayed**
Can you please advise how to edit this code as it includes likes and shares, and I only enabled sharing on my posts through Jetpack.
Thanks a lot!